# Conversion Problems in Java

Tags: java, string, int, type-conversion

I am getting a string to int conversion error. I have tried to seek answers here: [How to convert a String to an int in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-to-convert-a-string-to-an-int-in-java)
But i could not solve the issue.
My code is as follows:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class CarlysEventPrice
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    int total_Guests, total_Price, price_Per_Guest;
    total_Guests = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please input the number of guests");
    int total_Guests = Integer.parseInt(total_Guests);
    total_Price = price_Per_Guest * total_Guests;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                  "************************************************\n" +
                                  "* Carly's makes the food that makes it a party *\n" +
                                  "************************************************\n");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                  "The total guests are " +total_Guests+ "\n" +
                                  "The price per guest is " +price_Per_Guest+ "\n" +
                                  "The total price is " +total_Price);
    boolean large_Event = (total_Guests >= 50);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                  "Is this job classified as a large event: " +large_Event);      

    }
}
```

my code is showing this error:

```
CarlysEventPrice.java:10: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int
      total_Guests = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please input the number of guests");
                                                ^
CarlysEventPrice.java:11: error: variable total_Guests is already defined in method main(String[])
        int total_Guests = Integer.parseInt(total_Guests);
            ^
CarlysEventPrice.java:11: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String
        int total_Guests = Integer.parseInt(total_Guests);
                                            ^
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
```

I am using jGrasp for programming, and i also tried it to compile using cmd but it gave the same error.
Thank you for helping.

Comment: `total_Guests` is already an `int`. You are trying to parse an `int` to an `int`, hence the error. `parseInt` method expects a String argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you defined a `total_Guests` variable twice (1) and tried to assign a `String` result of the `showInputDialog` method to the `int` variable (2).

To achieve what you actually want to:

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "--/--");
int totalGuests = Integer.parseInt(input);
```

Have a look at the [`showInputDialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object)) method declaration:

```
String showInputDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message)
^^^
```

You should understand that the `String` and the `int` (or the `Integer` wrapper) are totally different data types and in such the statically typed languages as Java is you are not allowed to perform conversions even a `String` `"12"` looks like an `int` `12`.

Comment: i removed the parseInt statement, but it still shows me one error. That is string cannot be converted to int

Answer (score 0):

1.`total_Guests` is an `int`, not a `String`. [Integer#parseInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) expects a `String`. 2. You declare `totalGuest` twice. Try

```
total_Guests = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Message"));
```

Also, give some initial value to `price_Per_Guest`, like

```
int total_Guests, total_Price, price_Per_Guest = 5;
```

or else it would give *variable not initialised error*.